# How do I register for process cancellation in activiti?

Tags: alfresco, activiti, business-process-management, bpmn

I have a process which "leaves a mess" after cancellation. Hence, I would like to register a  callback so I get the chance to clean up.

How do you do this in activiti ?

Comment: Cancellation of the workflow?

Comment: Terminate abnormally. Respond to whatever Workflowservice.cancelWorkflow does under the covers.

Comment: How are you cancelling the process?? But there is a cancel end-event that you can take advantage.,

Comment: I did not not look at the source, but after reading http://forums.activiti.org/content/cancel-process-instance-or-kill-instancedeployment I guess runtimeService.deleteProcessInstance is executed under the covers.

Answer (score 1):

An event mechanism has been introduced in Activiti 5.15, so I guess you'll get some sort of event on cancellation in a listener, such as:

```
<process id="testEventListeners">
  <extensionElements>
    <activiti:eventListener class="org.activiti.engine.test.MyEventListener" />
  </extensionElements>
```

Alfresco is at 5.13-something so that does not help me out. To solve the problem with Alfresco, your options for wiring up a cleanup mechanism are

1. Extend Workflowservice.cancelWorkflow
2. Write a "process garbage collector"

Answer (score 1):

You should look at using Compensation Events. The "cleanup" scenario is exactly what they are designed to handle, and while you can do exactly the same with regular events, Compensation events are a cleaner and more "standard" way of handling cleanup.

http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnBoundaryCompensationEvent